# Gradients in a general Euclidean space.

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives

Let $\mathcal{E}$ be an Euclidean vector space, that is, a finite dimensional vector space over the reals equipped with an inner product. Is it possible, or rather is it standard to define the gradient of a function $f:\mathcal{E}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$? I understand that for a general Hilbert space, the Fréchet derivative is usually adopted, but the Fréchet derivative and the gradient don't actually coincide, right?

if it is possible to define the gradient, how is it done? Let $Df(p):\mathcal{E} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the Fréchet derivative of $f$ at point $p \in \mathcal{E}$, does the gradient $\nabla f(p)$ of $f$ at $p$ satisfy

$$ Df(p)x = \langle \nabla f(p),x \rangle $$

for all $x \in \mathcal{E}$?

Comment: From what I understand the Fréchet derivative gives the Jacobian matrix in finite dimensions which is the gradient for real valued functions. If that's the case they should coincide.

Comment: I believe they don't actually coincide. If we take $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ for example, then the jacobian will be the transpose of the gradient vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, exactly. In finite dimensions the Fréchet derivative and gradient don't necessarily coincide, but are dual to each other and can be related in exactly the way you write. The Fréchet derivative is covariant and the gradient is contravariant.